# AngularJS Directive menu template by a json with submenu

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-directive

I'm a new student of angularJs.
I want to create a menu with submenus by a .json.
A dynamic menu where i can add menus and submenus by the same .json.

```
<a href="#" ng-repeat="item in menuHeader">{{item.NAV.menu[x].subItens[x].nome}} </a>
```

i think this is a way to acess a element inside other element, in view of i can have multiple submenus and menus.
I tried to do a For loop inside, but it is a .HTML template... So can anyone help me to resolve that or show me other way?

Here's a demo: [CLICK HERE!](http://plnkr.co/edit/WcK3tQYXU3AXRaczfhEp?p=preview)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this I hope it will work as per your expectation **:**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {
    var data = [
    {
        "NAV": {
            "menu": [

                {
                    "id": 0,
                    "nome": "Menu 1",
                    "subItens": [
                        {
                            "id": 0,
                            "nome": "SUB MENU 1"
                        },

                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "nome": "SUB MENU 2"
                        },

                        {
                            "id": 2,
                            "nome": "SUB MENU 3"
                        }
                    ]
                },

                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "nome": "Menu 2",
                    "subItens": [
                        {
                            "id": 0,
                            "nome": "SUB MENU 1_2"
                        },

                                                {
                            "id": 1,
                            "nome": "SUB MENU 2_2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "nome": "Menu 3",
                    "subItens": [
                        {
                            "id": 0,
                            "nome": "SUB MENU 1_3"
                        }
                    ]
                }

            ]
        }
    }
];

    $scope.menuLinks = data[0].NAV.menu;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li ng-repeat="link in menuLinks"><a href="{{link.url}}" class="{{link.sub && 'dropdown-toggle' || ''}}" data-toggle="{{link.sub && 'dropdown' || ''}}">{{link.nome}}
                        </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-show="link.subItens">
                                <li ng-repeat="subItem in link.subItens"> <a href="#123">{{subItem.nome}}</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I just change this line:

```
 <a href="#" ng-click="changeSub($index)">
```

and the condition:

```
ng-show="$index == currentID">
```

The $index gives me the exact local array. =)